# logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[32,60] labels_size=[32,131]

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to classify this fruits data using cnn . and when i fit the model using the classifier after making all the layers, i get this error at
" history = classifier ... " section below . which i am not able to solve for last two days. i have searched a lot but this doesn't seem to be working.
PS: Any hint's would also be appreciated.

here's my code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Fruits.ipynb

Automatically generated by Colaboratory.

Original file is located at
    https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AiGMVBshT9w-5T3fzzi3jyrJr0CVGv6A
"""

from google.colab import files

!pip install -q kaggle

uploaded = files.upload()

!mkdir -p ~/.kaggle
!cp kaggle.json ~/.kaggle/
!ls ~/.kaggle
!chmod 600 /root/.kaggle/kaggle.json

!kaggle kernels list — user hinaaslam1 — sort-by dateRun

!kaggle datasets download -d moltean/fruits 

#https://www.kaggle.com/moltean/fruits see the dataset at this link.

!unzip -q fruits.zip -d content

!ls

!pip install --upgrade keras
!pip install tensorflow

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image



no_of_classes = 60

# Initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), input_shape = (100, 100, 3), activation = 'relu'))

# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides= 2))

# Adding a convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides= 2))

# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(128, (5, 5), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides= 2))

# Adding a third convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(256, (5, 5), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.25))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides= 2))

# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.25))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.25))
classifier.add(Dense(units = no_of_classes, activation = 'sigmoid'))

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

Training = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/fruits-360/Training',
                                                 target_size = (100, 100),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')

Validation = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/fruits-360/Test',
                                            target_size = (100, 100),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')

"""# New Section"""

history = classifier.fit_generator(Training,
                         steps_per_epoch = 4000,
                         epochs = 25,
                         validation_data = Validation,
                         verbose = 1,
                         validation_steps = 4000)
classifier.summary()

tf.keras.models.save_model(
    model,
    filepath,
    overwrite=True,
    include_optimizer=True,
    save_format="tf",
    signatures=None
)
model.save("fruit.h5")

#Plotting graphs
acc = history.history['acc']
val_acc = history.history['val_acc']
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
 
epochs = range(len(acc))
 
plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'b', label='Training acc')
plt.plot(epochs, val_acc, 'r', label='Validation acc')
plt.title('Training and validation accuracy')
plt.legend()
 
plt.figure()
 
plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'b', label='Training loss')
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'r', label='Validation loss')
plt.title('Training and validation loss')
plt.legend()
 
plt.show()

name_of_classes = [ "Apple Braeburn", "Apple Golden 1", "Apple Golden 2", "Apple Golden 3" , "Apple Granny Smith" ,"Apple Red 1" ,"Apple Red 2" ,"Apple Red 3" ,"Apple Red Delicious" ,"Apple Red Yellow" ,"Apricot" ,"Avocado","Avocado ripe" ,"Banana" ,"Banana Red" ,"Cactus fruit" ,"Carambula" ,"Cherry" ,"Clementine" ,"Cocos" ,"Dates" ,"Granadilla" ,"Grape Pink" ,"Grape White" ,"Grape White 2" ,"Grapefruit Pink" ,"Grapefruit White" ,"Guava" ,"Huckleberry" ,"Kaki" ,"Kiwi" ,"Kumquats" ,"Lemon" ,"Lemon Meyer" ,"Limes" ,"Litchi" ,"Mandarine" ,"Mango" ,"Maracuja" ,"Nectarine" ,"Orange" ,"Papaya" ,"Passion Fruit" ,"Peach" ,"Peach Flat" ,"Pear" ,"Pear Abate" ,"Pear Monster" ,"Pear Williams" ,"Pepino" ,"Pineapple" ,"Pitahaya Red" ,"Plum" ,"Pomegranate" ,"Quince" ,"Raspberry" ,"Salak" ,"Strawberry" ,"Tamarillo" , "Tangelo"]

test_image = image.load_img('litchi.jpg', target_size = (100, 100))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
Training.class_indices
img = 'litchi.jpg'
Image.open(img)

test_image = image.load_img('banana.jpg', target_size = (100, 100))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
Training.class_indices
img = 'banana.jpg'
Image.open(img)

test_image = image.load_img('lmn.jpg', target_size = (100, 100))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
Training.class_indices
img = 'lmn.jpg'
Image.open(img)

test_image = image.load_img('hb.jpg', target_size = (100, 100))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
Training.class_indices
img = 'hb.jpg'
Image.open(img)

test_image = image.load_img('lmn.jpg', target_size = (100, 100))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
Training.class_indices
img = 'lmn.jpg'
Image.open(img)
```

Comment: Simply doing `number_of_classes=60` won't work. You will have to process your data such that it only has 60 classes or train your network for 131 (all) classes. The error is because the labels are 131 but your output neurons are only 60

Comment: Thanks for this , i understand this . I made number_of_classes=131 and it ran but after 2100/4000 steps in epoch 1/25 it ran out of parameters to train . sorry i am naive here in this , can you please tell me what should i exactly do to tackle this new error or make the model according to the 60 classes .

Comment: @SajanGohil I basically want to train it according to 60 fruit classes basically . so what can i do about that?

Comment: Since you are loading from directory, you can delete/move rest of the classes from the main folder (remove same folders from training and validation directories) and keep only 60 of them

Comment: ok thanks . I'll try doing that.